# ** and ## operations on countries

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern, geography

- *Oman* is the ** of *Romania*
- *Andorra* is the ** of ***Andorra***
- ***Tunisia*** is the ** of *Tunisia*
- ***Guinea-Bissau*** is the ** of *Guinea-Bissau*

---

- *Haiti* is the ## of *Lithuania*
- *Togo* is the ## of ***Colombia***
- ***Maldives*** is the ## of *Guatemala*
- ***Jordan*** is the ## of ***Bahrain***

---

- *Country A* is the ** of *Country B*
- *Country C* is the ** of *Country D*
- ***Country D*** is the ## of ***Country B***

---

**Identify the countries A, B, C and D.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The countries are:

> **A** Niger
>  **B** Nigeria
>  **C** Sudan
>  **D** South Sudan

The rule:

> If the country is written in *italics*, the operator works on the name of the country. If the country is written in ***bold italics***, the operator works on the name of the country's capital.
>
>  A ** B means that A must be a substring of B: R(**oman**)ia, **Andorra** la Vella,  (**Tunis**)ia and Guinea-**Bissau**. A ## B means that B contains all letters from A in any order: L**ith**uan**ia**, B**ogot**á, Guat**emal**a (Malé) and **Manam**a (Amman).
>
>  B and D are **Niger**ia and South **Sudan** with their capitals A**buja** and Juba.